# Get all distinct values from a column where another column has at least two distinct values for each value in the initial column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a very large dataset (20GB+) and I need to select all distinct values from column A where there are at least two other distinct values in column B for each distinct value on column A.

For the following dataframe:

```
| A | B |
|---|---|
| x | 1 |
| x | 2 |
| y | 1 |
| y | 1 |
```

Should return only x because it has two distinct values on column B, while y has only 1 distinct value.

The following code does the trick, but it takes a very long time (as in hours) since the dataset is very large:

```
def get_values(list_of_distinct_values, dataframe):
    valid_values = []
    for value in list_of_distinct_values:
        value_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['A'] == value]
        if len(value_df.groupby('B')) > 1:
            valid_values.append(value)
    return valid_values
```

Can anybody suggest a faster way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know if this will be faster, but it's worth a try since it doesn't involve iteration: 
`valid_values = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': 'nunique'})`, 
`valid_values = valid_values[valid_values['B'] >= 2]`

Comment: @Jacob - thank you. It did work and its much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem with the method `drop_duplicates()` of the dataframe. You need to use the parameters `subset` and `keep` (to remove all the lines with duplicates) :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ["x", "x", "y", "y"],
    'B': [1, 2, 1, 1],
})
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['A'])['A']
```